# Select specific element from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm facing the following problem. Having a XML with several nodes like this:

```
<positions>
    <position employee="A" positionid="00000800" />
    <position employee="B" positionid="00001400" />
    <position employee="C" positionid="00131900" />
    <position employee="D" positionid="00000890" />
</positions>
```

I am now looking for a XSLT transformation which is using a search variable for the element "positionid". So lets say I am using the positionid "00131900" as search parameter I need the following result after the XSLT transformation:

```
<position employee="C" positionid="00131900" />
```

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Remove the select attribute if a value is passed to the transformation -->
  <xsl:param name="searchInput"  select="'00131900'"/>

  <xsl:template match="position[@positionid=$searchInput]">
   <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDiMCa

Answer (score 0):

I would utilize a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key)** for this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="position-id"  select="'00131900'"/>

<xsl:key name="pos" match="position" use="@positionid" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('pos', $position-id)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Performance always depends on the processor. With only four elements, it's unlikely to make much difference. When it gets to a thousand elements, `xsl:key` should boost performance on almost any processor -- with the exception of an optimizing processor like Saxon-EE that creates the key for you automatically.

Comment: There should be 30k elements or so. Saxon is used as engine.